# Regex to Match Two Strings Including Anything in Between Without Line-Breaks

Tags: regex, match, minify

I want to replace all the .png extensions in my HTML to .webp
so I am doing the regex expressing to match the png links:

```
\.\/assets\/images\/.*\.png
```

This works ok if my HTML file has line breaks like this:

```
<picture>
<source class="d-block w-100" media="(max-width: 575px)"
srcset="./assets/images/slider/advertisers-pt.png">

<source class="d-block w-100"
media="(min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 768px)"
srcset="./assets/images/slider/advertisers-pt.png">

<img class="w-100" srcset="
./assets/images/slider/advertisers-ls.png"
src="./assets/images/slider/advertisers-ls.png" alt="">
</picture>
```

and it matches all the strings correctly.

but after it's minified, it's no longer working, and it matches the start string until the last occurrence of the second string with everything in between, so the following:

```
<picture><source class="d-block w-100" media="(max-width: 575px)"srcset="./assets/images/slider/advertisers-pt.png"><source class="d-block w-100"media="(min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 768px)" srcset="./assets/images/slider/advertisers-pt.png"><img class="w-100" srcset="./assets/images/slider/advertisers-ls.png" src="./assets/images/slider/advertisers-ls.png" alt=""></picture>
```

will have a match for:

```
./assets/images/slider/advertisers-pt.png"><source class="d-block w-100"media="(min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 768px)" srcset="./assets/images/slider/advertisers-pt.png"><img class="w-100" srcset="./assets/images/slider/advertisers-ls.png" src="./assets/images/slider/advertisers-ls.png
```

How can I do this with regex after my file is minified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `/S` non-whitespace character matcher instead of `.` matches to any:

`\.\/assets\/images\/\S*\.png`

[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8UaUUP/1)